# How to protect back-end api that revealed by front-end code?

Tags: web-applications, frontend, backend, api-design, software-design

My understanding of a web application's front end, correct me if I am wrong, is that buttons, links, and other interactions serve as encapsulated HTTP requests, which contains well-formatted data from user's activity on the page.

For example, when a user submits a new post, something like the following data(JSON)/form/query is sent as a POST/GET to some path on some back-end server(for example `http://some_server/message/post/new`) that handles the request.

```
{  
  "user_id": <some_id>,
  "message": <some_message>,
  .
  .
  .
  more_necessary_fields..
}
```

My question is that if the front end is some sort of desktop/ios application, the code should be compiled into binaries and the back-end server's address and paths should be well hidden. However, if the front-end is Javascript, where the code is served as a webpage for browsers and all paths and request formats are completely transparent, people can easily abuse the back-end services that are specifically designed for front-end code use only. What are some ways that this is handled in the industry? Am I completely off track and there are existing structures that fix this issue? If not, what are some ways that can protect the back-end services that limit the usage for front-end code only?

Note: 
 An example of the abuse is that for example, the request shown earlier is to submit a message, now since user able to obtain the request path and request format, they can directly and programmatically send POST/GET request to that path so that thousands of post can be uploaded.

Comment: Using a csrf token

Answer (score 0):

Usually we use cors to protect our backend.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control

This technique allow us to set an specific domain what will make the requests to our backend.
Also you can set what methods could be used from the client side if you are using a restful design.

Hope that can help you.